# Why do using return inside and outside of if and else blocks gives me different results?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Cant understand why do i need to write `return` inside each `if` and `else`, but not once after conditional statement`s block?
Proper `return` use

```
let arrayToList = arr => { 
  if(arr.length == 1)
  {
    let list = {
    value: arr.shift(),
    rest: null
    };
    return list;
  }
  else{
    let list = {
    value: arr.shift(),
    rest: arrayToList(arr)
    };
    return list;
  }
};

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
//{value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

Misuse

```
let arrayToList = arr => { 
  if(arr.length == 1)
  {
    let list = {
    value: arr.shift(),
    rest: null
    };
  }
  else{
    let list = {
    value: arr.shift(),
    rest: arrayToList(arr)
    };
  }
  return list;
};

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
//{
//value:    1
//rest: {
//value:    2
//rest: {value: 3, rest: null}
//}
//}
```

Comment: [The let statement declares a block-scoped local variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let);

Comment: Because let is scoped to the block. So the `list` you have outside is defined somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have `list` variable outside the function?

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking about, which is already well-answered.  But you could avoid all those issues with a simpler implementation, something like `const arrayToList = ([value, ...vals]) => value == undefined ? null : {value, rest: arrayToList (vals)}`

Comment: @ScottSauyet Did as you said `const arrayToList = vars => vars == false ? null : {value:vars.shift(), rest:arrayToList(vars)}`

Comment: @forty-four: glad it helped.  But I would be wary of your variant for two reasons: (1) `shift` mutates your input value, making it hard to reason about.  (2) The base case only works because of crazy JS type coercion rules that say that `[] == false` is `true`.  If you wanted to change to the more standard `===` (and this is required by many teams, most linters, and most style guides), then this would fail.  If you don't like my destructuring approach, you could test the array for existence and length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem involves [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Your problem is that you've defined list inside the if/else scope and not outside. This code would work in Python, but Javascript works differently. The solution is to define list in an exterior scope:

```
let arrayToList = arr => { 
  let list = {}
  if(arr.length == 1)
  {
    list = {
      value: arr.shift(),
      rest: null
    };
  }
  else{
    list = {
      value: arr.shift(),
      rest: arrayToList(arr)
    };
  }
  return list;
};
```

I happen to think it is more readable to do the following:

```
let arrayToList = arr => { 
  if(arr.length == 1)
  {
    return {
      value: arr.shift(),
      rest: null
    };
  }
  return {
    value: arr.shift(),
    rest: arrayToList(arr)
  };
};
```

But this is a mostly aesthetic consideration

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results -

```js
// List.js

const empty =
  null

const create = (value, rest = empty) =>
  ({ value, rest })
  
const fromArray = (a = []) =>            // <-- "arrayToList"
  a.length === 0
    ? empty
    : create(a[0], fromArray(a.slice(1)))

export { fromArray }
```

```
// Main.js

import { fromArray } from "./List"

const mylist =
  fromArray([1, 2, 3])
  
console.log(mylist)
// { value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } }
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your browser -

```js
const empty =
  null

const create = (value, rest = empty) =>
  ({ value, rest })
  
const fromArray = (a = []) =>
  a.length === 0
    ? empty
    : create(a[0], fromArray(a.slice(1)))

const mylist =
  fromArray([1,2,3])
  
console.log(mylist)
// { value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } }
```

Answer (score -1):

[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) creates blocked scoped variables. Change the declaration to use `var`.

```js
let arrayToList = arr => { 
  if(arr.length == 1) {
    var list = {
      value: arr.shift(),
      rest: null
    };
  } else {
    var list = {
      value: arr.shift(),
      rest: arrayToList(arr)
    };
  }
  return list;
};

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

Or, since you'll want list to start out as an object in either case, you can just set it up prior to the `if` and populate it based on the condition.

```js
let arrayToList = arr => { 
  // You know you want list to be an object
  // either way, so declare it ahead of time
  // and populate it later.
  let list = {};
  
  if(arr.length == 1) {
    list = {
      value: arr.shift(),
      rest: null
    };
  } else {
    list = {
      value: arr.shift(),
      rest: arrayToList(arr)
    };
  }
  return list;
};

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

Comment: Please don't encourage global variables!

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'm not. This is just a snippet. Hopefully, it would be contained within a larger (but not global scope), but I'm not going to post all my answers that way.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: ok, but I would not post an impure function when a pure function is no more difficult, as shown in the accepted answer.  But perhaps I'm just odd that way!  I know that the OP had it that way, but the OP was also looking for advice around this very problem.  Just moving that `let list = {}` line inside the function would be a large improvement.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Agreed. I just was attacking the specific problem raised in the question. But, you are right. Answer updated.